How to check the wifi state in .NET MAUI?
I am looking for a way to check whether the Wi-Fi of the phone is on or off in Dote NET MAUI. Internet connection status is not important, but I just need to check Wi-Fi status.
I used "WifiManager" and came across warnings that pointed to null values ​​and of course the program always encountered a null value when running and simulating.
I write the tested method below:

I created an interface called IWifiService

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WifiTest9
{
    public interface IWifiService
    {
        bool IsWifiEnabled();
    }
}


Then I created a class specially for android in Platforms/Android

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Net.Wifi;
using WifiTest9.Platforms.Android;
using Microsoft.Maui;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls;


[assembly: Dependency(typeof(WifiService))]
namespace WifiTest9.Platforms.Android
{
    public class WifiService : IWifiService
    {
        public bool IsWifiEnabled()
        {
            var currentActivity = Platform.CurrentActivity;

            var wifiManager = (WifiManager)currentActivity.GetSystemService(Context.WifiService);

            return wifiManager.IsWifiEnabled;
        }
    }
}

These two lines of code that I am rewriting below are the same two lines where we encounter the warning of null values.
var wifiManager = (WifiManager)currentActivity.GetSystemService(Context.WifiService);

return wifiManager.IsWifiEnabled;


and finally I used them in MainPage.xaml.cs

private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckWiFiStatus();
}

private void CheckWiFiStatus()
{
    var wifiService = DependencyService.Get<IWifiService>();
    bool isWifiEnabled = wifiService.IsWifiEnabled();

    if (isWifiEnabled)
    {
        wifiStatusLabel.Text = "Wifi is ON";
    }
    else
    {
        wifiStatusLabel.Text = "Wifi is OFF";
    }
}

In addition, I found another way in the Microsoft documentation, but I don't know how to use it, and I will put the link with the code below.
public virtual bool IsWifiEnabled { [Android.Runtime.Register("isWifiEnabled", "()Z", "GetIsWifiEnabledHandler")] get; }

Link:
WifiManager.IsWifiEnabled Property

Why are you writing Dependency services in a MAUI app?

Because I created a class specially for android platform and defining a dependency system can make the code more understandable.

I mean you don't need dependency service you can use internal dependency injection in maui

You are right. but I had not paid attention to Access_Wifi_State in android.manifest.xaml and I could check the wifi state comfortable(without any injection).


In addition, I found another way in the Microsoft documentation, but I
don't know how to use it

You can achieve this by invoking platform code.
Based on the official sample code InvokePlatformCodeDemos, I achieved this function on my side, you can refer to the following code:
1.create a class WifiStateService.cs on folder Services.ConditionalCompilation
using Android.Net.Wifi;

namespace InvokePlatformCodeDemos.Services.ConditionalCompilation
{
    public class WifiStateService
    {
        public bool GetWifiStateEnabled() {

#if ANDROID
            bool isEnabled = false;

            WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.WifiService);

            isEnabled = wifiManager.IsWifiEnabled;

            return isEnabled;

#endif
        }
    }
}

2.add a button on page MainPage and call the WifiStateService defined above.
using ConditionalCompilationWifiStateService = InvokePlatformCodeDemos.Services.ConditionalCompilation.WifiStateService;

    private void Button_Clicked_CheckWifiState(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var wifiStateService = new ConditionalCompilationWifiStateService();
        bool wifiIsEnabled = wifiStateService.GetWifiStateEnabled();

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(" the value of  wifiIsEnabled is: " + wifiIsEnabled);
    }

Note:
Remember to add the following permission to file AndroidManifest.xml on android platform.
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"  />


thank you so much
you are completely right, Unfortunately I didn't see your answer earlier and I fixed it with a slight difference about few minutes ago Whereas if I had checked the message earlier, the problem would have been solved faster.

Simplified answer
#if ANDROID
using Android.Content;
using Android.Net.Wifi;
#endif

        private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
#if ANDROID
            var wifiManager = (WifiManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.WifiService);
            if(wifiManager.IsWifiEnabled)
            {
                WifiStateLabel.Text = "Wifi State: ON";
            }
            else
            {
                WifiStateLabel.Text = "Wifi State: OFF";
            }
#endif

thanks to
Jessie Zhang -MSFT and
FreakyAli
